# Why get 404 Ajax not found error in my code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a trouble in my code.
I'm trying to execute my code but i get this error: `404 (Not Found)` working with `get` method.

This is my `html` code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Problema</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="funciones.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Vote esta foto</h1>
    <div class="box caja1">
        Nombre:<input type="text" id="nombre" size="20"><br>
        Voto:<select id="voto">
          <option value="0" selected>seleccione</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="button" id="boton1" value="votar">
    </div>
    <div class="box caja2" id="resultados"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my `javascript` code.

```
var peticion;

function inicio() {
  document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", funcion_ajax, false);
}

function funcion_ajax() {
  var voto = parseInt(document.getElementById('voto').value);
  var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  if (voto !== "" && voto !== 0 && nombre !== "") {
    peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
    peticion.onreadystatechange = procesarRespuesta;
    peticion.open('GET', 'ajax.php?puntaje=' + voto + '&nombre=' + nombre, true);
    peticion.send(null);
  }
}

function procesarRespuesta() {
  var resultados = document.getElementById("resultados");
  if (peticion.readyState === 4) {
    resultados.innerHTML = peticion.responseText;
  }
  else {
    resultados.innerHTML = 'Cargando...';
  }
}

window.onload = inicio;
```

And this is my `php` code.

```
<?php

  $ar=fopen("puntaje.txt","a") or
    die("No se pudo abrir el archivo");

  fputs($ar,"<tr><td>".$_GET['nombre']."</td><td>".$_GET['puntaje']."</td></tr>");
  fclose($ar);

  $ar=fopen("puntaje.txt","r") or
    die("No se pudo abrir el archivo");

  $tabla = "<table><thead><tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Puntuación</th></tr></thead></thead><tbody>";

  while (!feof($ar)) {
    $linea=fgets($ar);
    $tabla .= $linea;
  }

  $tabla .= "</tbody></table>";

  echo utf8_encode("<h6>Votación correcta !!</h6>");
  echo "<h4>Resultados: </h4>";
  echo utf8_encode($tabla);
  fclose($ar);

?>
```

Comment: The URL you're using doesn't match the path of the file you've put on the server.

Comment: Add a forward slash to your URL. `'/ajax.php?puntaje='`

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log('ajax.php?puntaje=' + voto + '&nombre=' + nombre)`?

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm so noob, the name of my phpfile is ```ajax2``` not ```ajax``` ... Sorry and thanks for help me!

Answer (score 0):

The name of my php file is `ajax2`, not `ajax`.

`peticion.open('GET', 'ajax.php?puntaje=' + voto + '&nombre=' + nombre, true);` is the correct 13 line.